# how to make a efficient filter in python

Tags: python

I have a problem with two very large files(each more then 1.000.000 entries) in python:
I need to generate a filter and I dont know why, I have two files like this:

```
1,2,3
2,4,5
3,3,4
```

and the second

```
1,"fege"
2,"greger"
4,"feffg"
```

the first item of each file row is always the ID. Now I want to filter the Lists, that the first list only contains items which ID's are in the second file. For this example the result should be:

```
1,2,3
2,4,5
```

how to make this in a very fast way? the core problem is, that each list is very very long. I used s.th. like this:

```
[row for row in myRows if row[0] == item[0]]
```

but this take a long time to run throw. (more than 30 days)

Comment: No, they are not ordered

Comment: But it would be possible to order it before.

Comment: Well, if it's possible to order before - how are they generated? If they're in some kind of DB, can't it do a join or similar operation before exporting?

Comment: Can you read both files into memory?

Comment: @reptilicus even just the keys of the second file will do by the looks of it

Comment: I think I would put them in sqlite and then do an inner join on id, then dump the results back out to csv. . .

Comment: yes I can read both in memory

Comment: no its not in any kind of DB

Comment: I would recommend doing it with sqlite or some other database ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[row for row in myRows if row[0] == item[0]]
```

is doing a linear scan for each `item`. If you use a `set` instead, you can bring this down to an expected constant time operation. First, read in the second file to get a `set` of valid ids:

```
with open("secondfile") as f:
    # note: only storing the ids, not the whole line
    valid_ids = set(ln.split(',', 1)[0] for ln in f)
```

Then you can filter the lines of the first file using the set `valid_ids` as

```
with open("firstfile") as f:
    matched_rows = [ln for ln in f if ln.split(',')[0] in valid_ids]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are only interested in the first field. If so, you could try something like:

```
def _id(s):
  return s[:s.index(',')]

ids = {}
for line in open('first-file'):
 ids[_id(line)] = line
for line in open('second-file'):
 k = _id(line)
 if k in ids:
  print ids[k]
```